# Change mat-paginator's [pageSizeOption] font-size and font-family

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, paginator

I have a mat-paginator in my application but I can't seem to change the font-size of the [pageSizeOptions] when it is displaying.

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 30]"></mat-paginator>
```

I mean, the "10" is so small compared the "items per page" that is written right next to it.

CSS won't work even with :

```
.mat-paginator {
    font-family: 'Raleway'!important;
    font-size: large!important;
}
```

I've searched for a solution using the theme.scss :

```
$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: '"Raleway", "sans-serif"',
  $body-2:        mat-typography-level(16px, 24px, 600)
);

@include mat-core($custom-typography);
```

But no success. Do you guys have any idea how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use ::ng-deep on your style file:

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-value {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

::ng-deep .mat-option-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: I was applying the css to the wrong element, gosh. Thank you!